# Finding a specific key from a Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this code I am working with.  It needs to compare keys from a dictionary.  If the keys match then the values need to be compared to see if they are the same, if they are not I need to write the key along with both descriptions (value from first dictionary, and value from the second one).  I have read about TryGetValue, but it doesn't seem to be what I need.  Is there a way to retrieve the value from the second dictionary that has the same key as in the first dictionary?

Thank you

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dictionaryOne) 
        {
            if (dictionaryTwo.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                //Compare values
                //if values differ
                //Write codes and strings in format
                //"Code: " + code + "RCT3 Description: " + rct3Description + "RCT4 Description: " + rct4Description

                if (!dictionaryTwo.ContainsValue(item.Value))
                {
                    inBoth.Add("Code: " + item.Key + " RCT3 Description: " + item.Value + " RCT4 Description: " + );
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //If key doesn't exist
                //Write code and string in same format as input file to array
                //Array contains items in RCT3 that are not in RCT4
                rct3In.Add(item.Key + " " + item.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, `TryGetValue` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: How have you tried using `TryGetValue`? Can you show an example of you called it? (It is exactly what you need ...).

Comment: I have tried to use it, but I was putting in the wrong values (as compared to the answers below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply access the item in the second dictionary by

```
dictionaryTwo[item.Key]
```

This is safe once you've confirmed that there is an item with that key, as you've done in your code.

Alternatively, you can use TryGetValue:

```
string valueInSecondDict;
if (dictionaryTwo.TryGetValue(item.Key, out valueInSecondDict)) {
    // use "valueInSecondDict" here
}
```

Comment: I feel dumb, should have known to use the indexer

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to retrieve the value from the second dictionary that has the same key as in the first dictionary?

Why not use the indexer ?

```
dictionaryTwo[item.Key]
```